# Prevent white space disappearing from an XML element with mixed content

Tags: php, whitespace, domdocument

When using PHP's DOMDocument with preserveWhiteSpace set to false and formatOutput set to true, white space in mixed content is not consistently preserved, even within the same element.

```
Source XML:
<p><span>one</span> <span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>

Expected output:
<p><span>one</span> <span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>

Actual output (space lost between "one" and "two"):
<p><span>one</span><span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>
```

Using another example shows that in some cases the white space is preserved:

```
$examples = array(
    '<p>text <span>one</span> <span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>',
    '<p><span>one</span> <span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>',
);

foreach ($examples as $example) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadXML($example);
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    print $doc->saveXML();
}

// <p>text <span>one</span> <span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>
// <p><span>one</span><span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>
```

I'm guessing that the heuristic which libxml uses to detect mixed content doesn't look forwards within an element, so only starts to preserve the empty text nodes once a text node containing actual text has been found.

Is this a) a bug in libxml (even though it warns that automatic formatting can be dangerous) and/or b) something that can be avoided using a DTD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to prevent white space being lost by using a DTD and declaring the element as mixed content:

```
<?php

$xml = '<!DOCTYPE p [
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA|span)*>
<!ELEMENT span (#PCDATA)>
]>
<p><span>one</span> <span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$doc->formatOutput = true;

print $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);

// <p><span>one</span> <span>two</span> text <span>three</span> <span>four</span></p>
```